# jQuery Slider Value IE bug

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-ui, slider

I work for an online education company, we're trying to develop some simple apps for helping demonstrate topics. I need to use the jQuery UI slider and retrieve the value from it. It works fantastic in FF and Chrome, but in IE it bugs out.

In IE9, the salary slider doesn't work and the graph associated with it won't work either. 
In IE8, the numbers (max, min, current value) all show up as web address rather than the numbers they are supposed to be.

I cannot find any support or similar bugs anywhere. I've tried different versions of jQuery, different order of jQuery, different placements of the code (external or in the document or combination of the two), I cannot find a solution to the problem.

Specifically, I'm noticing it's the code that calls the value from the separate sliders: $("#retireSlider").slider("option", "value"); that is not grabbing data properly.

The example with all the code is the very last one on this page: www.eoigraphics.com/animations/pf/imageRequests.html

I appreciate any help.

Thank you,

-Cory

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at my debug screen and it's telling me there's an issue at line256 in calcFunctions.js:

```
function addCommas(nStr) {
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

This line:

```
x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2')
```

The error it's showing is: Object doesn’t support this property or method.

I seem to recall something about issues with global variables having the same name as element ids in internet explorer. Not sure if that's the cause though